# Parse server side non html tag

Tags: html, jsoup, jericho-html-parser

I wish parse a Play framework template File, with tags like this ..

```
#{form @UneReponses.modifier(unereponse.id), method:'PUT', id:'creationForm'}
```

How to create a tag with this kind of syntax ?

Begin with

(hashtag){form --> name of tag

@UneReponses.modifier(unereponse.id) --> name

method:'PUT' and  id:'creationForm' --> attribute

} end of tag;

Any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: what about using a regex?

Comment: I want parse groovy play syntax and HTML (a href, img, ressource, etc). I want modify this links after.